# how to rsync from one server to another with the path defined by variable say $PATH?

Tags: bash, variables, copy, rsync

Hi i want to copy data from one server to another using rsync but my path to copy data is stored in a variable which i got from the database.

Comment: Don't use `$PATH` as a variable in your program; call it something else.

Comment: to add to `Amber` remark. `PATH` is already used, it holds the list of directories to search executables in. Overriding it is perilous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read rsync's man page and what it tells about trailing slashes:

> A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating an additional directory level at the destination. You can think of a trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name", but in both cases the attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the containing directory on the destination. In other words, each of the following commands copies the files in the same way, including their setting of the attributes of /dest/foo:

```
   rsync -av /src/foo /dest
   rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the actual rsync call it's a bit difficult to understand what is happening. OTOH, "to make it copy only the updated files" depends on what you mean by "updated". From the man page:

> -c, --checksum
>
> This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been
>   changed and are in need of a transfer.
>   Without this option, rsync uses a
>   "quick check" that (by default) checks
>   if each file’s size and time of last
>   modification match between the sender
>   and receiver. This option changes this
>   to compare a 128-bit checksum for each
>   file that has a matching size.
>   Generating the checksums means that
>   both sides will expend a lot of disk
>   I/O reading all the data in the files
>   in the transfer (and this is prior to
>   any reading that will be done to
>   transfer changed files), so this can
>   slow things down significantly.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your treating the directory as a file.

**Setup**

```
mkdir foo
touch foo/a
mkdir /tmp/foo
```

**Problem**

```
rsync -av foo /tmp/foo
```

**Solution**

```
rsync -av foo/ /tmp/foo  # Notice foo has a trailing '/'
rsync -av foo/. /tmp/foo # Another way to do the same thing
```

Comment: I would just change `rsync --progress --stats -aHrvxz "$SECONDARY:$d/." $d`